# Why I'm not getting Product handle into my page.js file

Tags: next.js, shopify, next.js13

I'm new to shopify as well as Nextjs 13. I'm trying to build customs storefront using Nextjs.
Below code maps the data fetched from graphql. I want to make the route dynamic, passing Product Handle in the Link tag. I want Product Handle into page.js file to make graphql query in shopify store.

Below is Homepage.js file where I'm passing Product Handle in Link.

```
   {products.map((product) => (
                        <Link key={product.node.id}
                            href={`/products/${product.node.handle}`}
                            // href={{
                            //     pathname: `/product/${product.node.handle}`,
                            //     query: { productId: product.node.handle },
                            // }}
                            legacyBehavior>)}
```

Below code is of Page.js, where I want Product handle.

```
function ProductDetails() {
const router = useRouter();
const { query } = router.query;
console.log("Query", query);

// console.log("router", router);
// const productHandle = query.productId;
// console.log(productHandle);

const searchParams = useSearchParams();
console.log("searchParams", searchParams);

return (
  <div>
    <h1>Product Details</h1>
    {/* {productId && <ProductDetailsPage productId={productId} />} */}
  </div>
);
}

export default ProductDetails;
```

There Error I'm getting is.

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'query' of 'router.query' as it is undefined.

Looking for solution for above problem. Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You try to destructure it the wrong way. Either:

```
const query = router.query;
// or 
const {<the name of your route param>} = router.query;
// const { query } = router.query; <-- from your code would only work if the route was [query].js
```